# Question about REMIX Deployments Environments

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

I'm currently learning to code with Solitidy. In the video I'm watching, in the first example, the contract was deployed using JavaScript VM environment, but I don't have that one. My options are:

1. Remix VM (Berlin)
2. Remix VM (London)
3. Injected Provider - Metamask
4. Hardhat Provider
5. Ganache Provider
6. Foundry Provider
7. Wallet Connect
8. External Http Provider
9. L2 - Optimism Provider
10. L2 Arbitrum Provider

Which one is an equivalent to JavaScript VM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this link: https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html#environment

In **Environment** section you will see the following:

> Remix VM (London): For connecting to a sandbox blockchain in the browser. The Remix VM (previously called JavaScript VM) ...

So you should keep the Remix VM (London) env.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of any of the first two options you have, but preferably use remix vm (london).